# Invert time on given date in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For a dataframe containing start and end times I would like to "invert" it's times for a given date. There certainly is a "brute force" method to do it by looping through the dataframe and having a lot of if conditions, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way, like with backfill/forwardfill.

Consider it as having a dataframe where working hours are represented by rows with start and end time and what I ultimately want is the freetime of this date.
The dataframe is ordered in monotonic increasing start times and has cut offs at date change, so a time starting at e.g. 2019-04-04 22:00 and ending at 2019-04-05 04:00 is represented by two rows 2019-04-04 22:00 to 2019-04-05 00:00 and 2019-04-05 00:00 to 2019-04-05 04:00. This should make the problem easier.

Code for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime.date(2019, 4, 4), datetime.date(2019, 4, 5), datetime.date(2019, 4, 5)],
                   'start': [pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 4, 10), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 0), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 14)],
                   'end': [pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 4, 16), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 4), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 18)]})
```

So starting from this:

```
2019-04-04   2019-04-04 10:00:00   2019-04-04 16:00:00
2019-04-05   2019-04-05 00:00:00   2019-04-05 04:00:00
2019-04-05   2019-04-05 14:00:00   2019-04-05 18:00:00
```

I would expect the result to be a dataframe like this:

```
2019-04-04   2019-04-04 00:00:00   2019-04-04 10:00:00
2019-04-04   2019-04-04 16:00:00   2019-04-05 00:00:00
2019-04-05   2019-04-05 04:00:00   2019-04-05 14:00:00
2019-04-05   2019-04-05 18:00:00   2019-04-06 00:00:00
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to use the result? Unless everything is a consistent 12 hour shift, 7 days a week and you don't cross daylight saving time, the results cannot possibly match the length of the existing datetime values. I.e. you will not have a list of equivalent length that could be used as new datetime values

Comment: @roganjosh his expected output makes it clear. 3 rows in the beginning, 4 at the end

Comment: @RafaelC was on my phone at the time. Now back at PC and can see the pattern, thanks. Will have a think.

Comment: Is it a typo in cell (3,3) in the input table: `2019-04-06 18:00:00`. Should be `2019-04-05 18:00:00`

Comment: @gdlmx yes you are right, sorry for the typo. Corrected it!

Comment: It gets really easy to do if you use `pyinterval` and intersect your intervals. Can't try it right now, maybe later ! But try and let me know if it works ;}

Comment: Can you tell us more about your input data: Are the rows strictly ordered and the timestampts monotonic increasing? Do you need to insert "natural day boundaries" (e.g. `2019-04-06 00:00:00`) to the free time intervals (e.g. from 2019-04-05 18:00:00 to 2019-04-06 09:00:00)?

Comment: @gdlmx yes it is monotonic orderd in the staring time and there are artificial cut offs at date boundaries. Even for the "free time" this is desired

Comment: @RafaelC I had a look at PYINTERVAL (really cool module, thanks for sharing), however the one thing I need I cannot find there or do not understand it well enough. That would be to exclude intervals from a bigger over-spanning interval

Comment: There's not such a function for [being mathematical  rigor](https://github.com/taschini/pyinterval/issues/9). However it will be easy to write a loop to do so. Just take the end of one interval and the start of the next interval to construct a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply enough with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). The problem comes with the last row that I'm trying to work out how best to reconstruct.

EDIT: I gave it my best shot on the last row but it ends up being a clumsy mess. I'd be happy for any feedback on that last row. In principle, using `shift` would make this super easy. You could obviously just drop `start` and `end` before adding the last row, I just went with showing how to do it with no data loss.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [dt.date(2019, 4, 4), dt.date(2019, 4, 5), dt.date(2019, 4, 5)],
                   'start': [pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 4, 10), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 0), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 14)],
                   'end': [pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 4, 16), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 4), pd.Timestamp(2019, 4, 5, 18)]})

df = df[['date', 'start', 'end']]

saved_shift_ending = df['end'].iloc[-1]  # we want end of last shift
saved_end_date = df['date'].iloc[-1]     # we also want the date value

start_date = df['date'].min()
end_date = (df['date'].max() + dt.timedelta(days=1))

df['other_start'] = df['end'].shift(1)
df['other_end'] = df['start']

df.loc[0, 'other_start'] = start_date # The first value is NaT after shift

last_row = pd.DataFrame([[saved_end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
                         np.nan, 
                         np.nan, 
                         saved_shift_ending, 
                         end_date]],
                        columns=['date', 'start', 'end', 'other_start',
                                'other_end'])

df = df.append(last_row)

df.drop(['start', 'end'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks @roganjosh, `.shift(1)` was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

roganjosh answers the general case, however I had to look at daily "free time" and for that I had to add in some artificial date boundaries as rows with zero time between start and end. In the end `.shift()` was what I was after.
I packed it into a function to increase reusability and if anyone has a more elegant solution please feel free to share.

Here is my code:

```
def invertDailyTimes(df, dateCol, starttimeCol, endtimeCol):
    """
    requires a input df with a date column (dateCol) and two timestamp columns (starttimeCol, endttimeCol)
    which is monotonic ordered in (starttimeCol, endttimeCol)
    """
    dates = list(df[dateCol].unique())
    for d in dates:
        df_tmp = df[df[dateCol] == d].iloc[0:1]
        df_tmp[starttimeCol] = pd.Timestamp(d)
        df_tmp[endtimeCol] = pd.Timestamp(d)
        df_tmp = df_tmp.append(df_tmp)
        df_tmp[starttimeCol].iloc[-1] = pd.Timestamp(d + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        df_tmp[endtimeCol].iloc[-1] = pd.Timestamp(d + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        df_tmp[dateCol].iloc[-1] = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        df = df.append(df_tmp)

    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df.sort_values(by=[starttimeCol, endtimeCol], inplace=True)

    df['invert_start'] = df[endtimeCol].shift(1)
    df['invert_end'] = df[starttimeCol]

    df = df[(abs(df['invert_start'] - df['invert_end']) < pd.Timedelta(days=1)) &
            (abs(df['invert_start'] - df['invert_end']) > pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))]

    df[starttimeCol] = df['invert_start']
    df[endtimeCol] = df['invert_end']
    df.drop(columns=['invert_start', 'invert_end'], inplace=True)

    return df
```