# How to calculate datetime difference between two cells in two rolls that groupby same specific properties?

Tags: python, for-loop, rows

I have a data set with subject, in-time and out-time. I want to calculate the time for every specific subject between the out-time and the next in-time (like readmission time). For every subject, it may has several different visit. SO how could I calculate it?

```
ipl_data = {'Subject': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'Kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Royals'],
   'In_time': ['2152-09-03 07:15:00', "2156-10-18 19:34:00",'2185-07-18 16:46:00','2190-02-23 05:23:00','2131-04-30 07:15:00',\
               '2131-05-12 19:49:00' ,'2134-05-10 11:30:00','2196-12-06 07:13:00','2198-08-02 04:49:00','2198-11-01 22:36:00',\
              '2199-10-20 12:05:00'],
   'Out_time': ['2152-09-08 19:10:00','2156-10-25 14:00:00','2185-07-20 16:00:00','2190-02-25 20:20:00','2131-05-08 14:00:00',\
                '2131-05-25 13:30:00','2134-05-20 13:16:00','2197-01-03 14:00:00','2198-10-26 14:55:00','2198-11-14 14:20:00',\
               '2199-10-23 17:30:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zswEF.png)

Expect result:
Time between two visits: Riders:30 days, Devils: 60 days, Kings: 10 days, 20 days, 30 days, Royals: 40 days, 50 days...

Comment: What is your expected result for Riders, Devils, Kings and Royals?

Comment: Does the out time for a row correspond to the in time for that row?

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55541273/4799172) and the other may be of some help to start

Comment: like for Riders, his time between two visits, while for people have more encounters, like Kings, the time between every two visits.

Comment: Yes, each rows represent one visit, but I want the time between two visits.

Comment: So for Riders:  2156-10-18 19:34:00 minus 2152-09-08 19:10:00?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right~